# Is an artinian subring of a local artinian ring local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings, artinian

> If $R$ is a local left artinian ring, and $A$ is a left artinian subring, is $A$ a local ring?

I can show that $rad A = A \cap rad R$ since $rad A$ and $rab R$ nilpotent ideals ($R$ and $A$ are artinian), and with the second isomorphism theorem, I can show that $A/rad A \cong (A + rad R) / rad R$. So I was hoping to show $(A + rad R) / rad R$ is a division ring, which would imply that $A$ is a local ring, but I'm not sure that I can show that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you assuming that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: No, I am not assuming $R$ is commutative. Does anything I showed imply I did?

Comment: @user439126 Saying "Artinian" without specifying sides or mentioning noncommutativity makes it a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes $A$ and $R$ share identity.

If $A$ is right Artinian, the idempotents lift from $A/J(A)$ to $A$.  If $A/J(A)$ has a nontrivial idempotent, so does $A$, but $R$ contains no nontrivial idempotents.

Then it can only be the case that $A/J(A)$ is a semisimple artinian ring with only trivial idempotents, and that amounts to a division ring.